# Error Opening SSCE table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am having problem in opening and viewing data in my SSCE table.  There are 3 tables in it, two are working fine but one is causing trouble.  I dropped the table and created a new one (same name) but again, the problem is the same.
Please see the problem message below:
[image]

The select statement:

> SELECT [PK], [AdmissionID], [Session], [Medium], [DateEnr], [FeeStatus], GuardianNIC], [FatherOccupation], [FatherIncome], [Cast], [Religion], [MotherName], [Address1], [Address2], [City], [PhNo], [MobNo], [PrevName], [PrevAdd], [PrevClass], [Class], [Section], [Remarks], [Picture], [FName], [GName], [BS1Name], [BS2Name], [BS3Name], [BS4Name], [BS1AdmNo], [BS2AdmNo], [BS3AdmNo], [BS4AdnNo], [BS1Class], [BS2Class], [BS3Class], [BS4Class], [BS1DOB], [BS2DOB], [BS3DOB], [BS4DOB] FROM [tblEnrollment] Where FName Like @FN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a comma in the wrong spot at character 200 of the select statement.

If you post the full text of the select statement, it should be easy to identify the offender.

I have added the select statement to the question.

The issue in what you posted is:

```
, GuardianNIC]
```

should be

```
, [GuardianNIC]
```

Also, if you are using like @FN, then @FN should leading and/or trailing % in order to work correctly.

Comment: SELECT [PK], [AdmissionID], [Session], [Medium], [DateEnr], [FeeStatus], GuardianNIC], [FatherOccupation], [FatherIncome], [Cast], [Religion], [MotherName], [Address1], [Address2], [City], [PhNo], [MobNo], [PrevName], [PrevAdd], [PrevClass], [Class], [Section], [Remarks], [Picture], [FName], [GName], [BS1Name], [BS2Name], [BS3Name], [BS4Name], [BS1AdmNo], [BS2AdmNo], [BS3AdmNo], [BS4AdnNo], [BS1Class], [BS2Class], [BS3Class], [BS4Class], [BS1DOB], [BS2DOB], [BS3DOB], [BS4DOB] FROM [tblEnrollment]
Where FName Like @FN

Comment: Could you help me on like statement too.  The one I have shown does not work

Comment: I have updated the answer with information that should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to test if this is works.

```
SELECT *  FROM tblEnrollment Where FName Like @FN
```

Regards